# How to disable manual input for JQuery UI Datepicker field?

Tags: php, jquery-ui, datepicker

I decided to use the JQuery UI Datepicker script for picking dates. Below is part of my code, and the way I integrated it into my PHP page:

```
<link type="text/css" href="css/south-street/jquery-ui-1.8.6.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.6.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    // Datepicker
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });
    //hover states on the static widgets
    $('#dialog_link, ul#icons li').hover(
        function() { $(this).addClass('ui-state-hover'); }, 
        function() { $(this).removeClass('ui-state-hover'); }
    );
});
</script>
```

And:

```
    // date picker (embeds JQuery script)
echo '<label for="datepicker">Date: </label>';
echo '<input type="text" name="datepicker" id="datepicker" />';
echo '<div id="datepicker"></div>';
```

Pretty much according to the JQuery UI instructions.

Now my question is: *how can I disable manual inputs in the text input field*? I only want the JQuery Datepicker script to be able to fill the text field. As far as I can see, the script currently prevents the user from entering any non-numerical characters into the text field, but any combination of numbers is allowed (therefore, gibberish like "95460829468" is allowed).

Answer (score 320, accepted):

When you make the input, set it to be readonly.

```
<input type="text" name="datepicker" id="datepicker" readonly="readonly" />
```

Comment: Amazingly simple solution. Seems to be working just as intended, many thanks!

Comment: If you add 'background-color: #fff !important; cursor: text !important;' it'll look totally normal...

Comment: I'd use a cursor pointer to make it look clickable

`<input ... readonly="readonly" style="cursor:pointer; background-color: #FFFFFF">`

Comment: This also works in an MVC page with
     new { @readonly="readonly" }

Comment: It works. But in my case, user can still change the date by hover on input and scrolling over it. I am using xdsoft datetimepicker, any solution for this problem??

Comment: This works, but I really wish the datepicker api had an option to do it

Comment: This solution does not let me clear the selected date.

Comment: This solution doesn't work combined with jQuery validate, or atleast it disables validation of this field

Comment: is it possible to make it unscrollable. Now the user can scroll to change the date

Answer (score 35):

I think you should add 
    **style="background:white;"** 
to make looks like it is writable

```
<input type="text" size="23" name="dateMonthly" id="dateMonthly" readonly="readonly"   style="background:white;"/>
```

Comment: 1. copy answer 2. add new attribute (I think you should add style="background:white;" to make looks like it is writable and "cursor: pointer" to make it look clickable) 3. ??????? 4. Profit

Comment: To be fair, the CSS tip was actually pretty helpful so that the input doesn't appear disabled.