# Disable manual input for datepicker without blocking mouse cursor

Tags: ruby-on-rails, input, datepicker, readonly, manual

I am using the jquery ui datepicker for my text boxes and have marked them as readonly to prevent manual input (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4164542/how-to-disable-manual-input-for-jquery-ui-datepicker-field)). The issue I still have is that when a user brings the mouse over the text box the cursor changes to a blocked cursor image. This gives an impression to the user that he cannot do anything with that field. Although if he goes ahead and clicks upon it, he would get the datepicker and can choose a date. My question is : Is there a way to elegantly handle this without writing all manipulating code for the mouse cursor.

Answer (score 0):

For example, by using the css cursor attribute. You can change it to the cursor you prefer.

I have this for my datepicker fields:

```
.form-control.datepicker {
  &[disabled], &[readonly] {
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

With this you change the cursor to pointer and keep the background-color to white while the input is disabled or readonly.