# JQuery date picker how to know user enters the data in DD/MM/YYYY format

Tags: jquery, vb.net, reporting-services

I am using a JQuery date picker in my project. I would like to know whether the user enters the input in DD/MM/YYYY after entering data in the datepicker text box? Or is it possible with a user can't enter date with out using date picker?  I am using the UI of Reporting services. So its not possible while clicking any button. I would like to check the details after user enters the data.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes it is possible to restrict the user from only selecting from the widget

Comment: Hi Karthikr,   how can u please give me the code. Thanks

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Comment: if you're going the disable typing route, [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4164542/how-to-disable-manual-input-for-jquery-ui-datepicker-field) is related.

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to force the user to use the date picker, set your textbox to read only, any also add an onclick event to it, which opens the datepicker.
For example put in the page_load event handler:

```
Sub Page_Load(ByVal Sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Textbox1.ReadOnly = True
End Sub
```

Comment: I am a fresher and I have no experience with JQuery. It would be great if you could provide me with the code snippet..